# the best dancer I ever saw

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

a. When I was in high school, there was this guy in our class who was the best dancer I ever saw.

Would you say that sentence corresponds to

1. When I was in high school, there was this guy in our class who was the best dancer I ever saw in that period of time (presumably when I was in high school)

or

2. When I was in high school, there was this guy in our class who was the best dancer I **have ever seen**.

or

3. When I was in high school, there was this guy in our class who was the best dancer I **had ever seen**.

?

Comment: "...I had ever seen" definitely means 'before that time', and "...I have ever seen" means 'in my whole life'. "The best I ever saw" sounds like American usage to me, but I would understand it also to mean 'in my whole life'.

Comment: @KateBunting To my AmE ear it sounds like something said by an AmE speaker who never uses the perfect, neither present nor past. There are speakers of AmE who don't use it. But to indicate that **ever** means "in my whole life (up to now)" they would probably say "This guy back in high school **is** the best dancer I ever saw".   Some speakers whose (American) English is farther from standard  than simply not using the perfect would even say "best dancer I ever **seen**".    Do these AmE speakers not have counterparts in England?

Comment: And there's also "the best dancer I  **ever did see**".

Comment: @TimR - Rightly or wrongly, I think of 'the best I have ever seen' as typically British and 'the best I ever saw' typically American, though not necessarily unknown here. It's like adverts saying 'X just got better', which sounds American to me but is increasingly used in the UK.

Comment: The overall impression from four uses of **was** is that it means "3. had ever seen".